# i have an array of objects i wanna check if an elements exist in this array javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter

i have this array of objects

```
data= [
     { name: "name1",
       email: "email1@gmail.com"},
     { name: "name2",
       email: "email2@gmail.com"},
     { name: "name3",
       email: "email3@gmail.com"},
]
```

i have the email on one of the users

> "email2@gmail.com"

i want to redirect the user in the users page if his email exist in the data array else redirect him to register page

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data= [
     { name: "name1",
       email: "email1@gmail.com"},
     { name: "name2",
       email: "email2@gmail.com"},
     { name: "name3",
       email: "email3@gmail.com"},
]

const email = "email2@gmail.com"

console.log(data.some(item => item.email === email))
```

returns `true` if found.
replace `some` with `find` to get the first element that matches

Comment: yes it works with some , because i need boolean result

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```js
const data = [{
    name: "name1",
    email: "email1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    name: "name2",
    email: "email2@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    name: "name3",
    email: "email3@gmail.com"
  },
]

const email = "email2@gmail.com"

console.log(data.find(item => item.email === email))
```